# Error message in CommCare when trying to record audio

Tags: commcare, audio

I am seeing the following error message:

> No activity found to handle: audio capture

when attempting to record a sound:

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

CommCare doesn't have the capacity to record audio natively, so in order to capture audio in a CommCare application, users need to install a 3rd party audio-recording app from the Play Store. We recommend [RecForge Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dje073.android.audiorecorderlite) for this because it is known to work well with CommCare.